# How to set my own QDialog Form instead QGIS QgsAttributeForm

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, features, digitizing

I'm working in a QGIS plugin which its functionality is to facilitate the creation of custom attribute forms with complex logic to QGIS users without python knowledge. In order to do this, the user has to write a custom .json file with all data of layers, attributes, custom rules between widgets, form widgets etc. This file is loaded by a parser and the result is a QgsVectorLayer and a QDialog (A form) with the correct widgets structure and rules (Similar to QGIS form). Then, the layer is added to QGIS and the dialog is opened when user uses my own custom 'Add feature' tool.

I would like to know if I can replace the default QgsAttributeForm with my own QDialog Form so that I can use all QGIS tools (addFeature, editFeature...) with my own dialog instead of the QGIS autogenerated form. If not I have to duplicate all digitizing and editing tools because all of them open the autogenerated default QGIS form.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour].  A question asking for help with code should include a snippet of code that has been tested, and a description of what happens when you try it.  What have you tried, and what was the result?